# Mocking in ROS?

Tags: ros, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm creating tests for my project and I was wondering, is there a mocking package in ROS? I was using gtest for the tests itself so I was expecting gmock, or googlemock, to be in ROS too but I couldn't find it.. Should I just use gmock as if it was a regular gtest, without ROS?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36799/mocking-in-ros?/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-19**:
That would be great to have in a ROS context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is a simple interface for mocking subscribers , service and aciton servers .

http://www.ros.org/wiki/mock_objects

Hope that helps a little . Cheers

---

Originally posted by [afourast](https://answers.ros.org/users/2974/afourast/) with karma: 6 on 2012-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-12-06**:
I need to mock something apart from subscribers, services and action servers.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-06-19**:
Where can I find the sources of mock_objects?

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-11-24**:
Doesn't seem to exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be great to have.  We have been working hard to keep from doing extra work.  And currently mock is not available through our target platforms package managers.  I expect it to become available in the future.  At which point I'd expect us to start using it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-12-06**:
Have here been any updates related to mocking?
I tried to modify the gtest.cmake in /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/test to make it generate a gmock library similar to gtest in <catkin_workspace>/build, but could not achieve anything. cmake is not one of my strengths.

**Comment by [roboticom314](https://answers.ros.org/users/26759/roboticom314/) on 2016-07-22**:
Since Google Mock is not available (or is it in the 4 years since this post was made) on the target platform, what's the preferred way to mock certain functions when writing unit tests for ROS packages?

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2016-07-22**:
The best practices method is to copy the entire google-mock module and link them manually unlike gtest, using your own functions. Look at the ROS's gtest cmake to get more idea on how to do that. And no official progress on the ROS-framework for Google-mock has been made AFAIK.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-11-24**:
@tfoote are there plans to make core ros infrastructures such as `Subscriber`, `Publisher`, `ActionClient`, `ActionServer`, `ServiceClient` and `ServiceServer` (and their `SimpleXXX` variants) to implement interfaces so that we can create mocks ourselves using those interfaces?